# WIX CUSTOM ACTION CALL AFTER NEXT

Tags: wix

How can I make a call to my Custom Action dll when I click on Next button? Currently what I am doing is given below:

```
<CustomAction Id="TestingAction" BinaryKey="BIN_CustomAction" DllEntry="TestValue" Execute="deferred" Return="check" />
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="&amp;Next"></Control>
<Custom Action="TestingAction" After="Next"></Custom>
```

When I given `After ="Next"` which is my Next button i am getting error after building my application.

> Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixAction:InstallUISequence/Next' in
>   section 'Product:*.

How to resolve is issue and can anyone help me how to make a call to CustomAction after i click on Next Button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to schedule the deferred custom action to a certain sequence and run it after a custom action called Next, which obviously doesn't exist. You should go a totally different way to call custom action on button click.

Follow the steps below:

- create a custom action. It must be immediate (`execute='immediate'`) and should never ever change the state of the target system
- author a `Control` element - the button you'd like to trigger the event
- finally, author a `Publish` element as a child of the `Control`, which publishes the `DoAction` event

Here's a full sample from the WiX sources how to print EULA on a button click:

```
<Control Id="Print" Type="PushButton" X="88" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIPrint)">
  <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIPrintEula">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

Obviously, the `Control` element should be a child of `Dialog` element.
And the custom action is defined like this:

```
<CustomAction Id="WixUIPrintEula" BinaryKey="WixUIWixca" DllEntry="PrintEula" Return="ignore" Execute="immediate" />
```

Hope this helps.